# ubuntu network settings equivalent in centos 7

Tags: networking, centos, linux-networking, centos7

I have in a ubuntu server an interface setup as the following

(in /etc/network/interfaces)

```
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask 255.255.255.255
broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
post-up route add xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev eth0
post-up route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
post-down route del xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev eth0
post-down route del default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I am wondering how can I use this configuration in a centos 7 server
(in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens18)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `nmtui` command-line tool (from the package *NetworkManager-tui*) to configure the network settings (you can set up custom routes there), and then have a look at the configuration file it produces. I have found that a lot easier than trying to edit the NetworkManager configuration files directly.

Comment: The tool works great, but I added the file play way...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so this is how

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens18

```
DEVICE=ens18
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
PEERDNS=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
IPADDR=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
GATEWAY=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ARP=yes
HWADDR=MA:MAC:VI:RT:UEL:LE
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ens18

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ens18
default via xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ens18
```